# PHP SoapClient hangs on second call

Tags: php, soap

I'm trying to send more than one request to a Webservice:

```
<?php

$client = new SoapClient(__DIR__ . '/../services.xml', 
                         array('local_cert' => 'cert.pem',
                               'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));

var_dump($client->testSum(1, 2)); # => int(3)
var_dump($client->testSum(1, 2)); # no output ...
```

If I create another client ($client2), I manage to call again... but I'd like to use the same client.

However, I can call this WS twice with SoapUI.

Comment: You forget apostrophe before `cert.pem`

Comment: Thanks. I missed when copying from my editor.

Comment: Second call print nothing or `NULL`? `var_dump` always show type of variable. If in your case it's not printed, then I think your code throw errors. Error displaying is enabled in your php.ini?

Comment: Try to set `exceptions` option for SoapClient to true.

Comment: ...and `trace` option to `1`

Comment: I've managed to call a second time. My server was with too many httpd processes running. I restarted the server and the problem is gone.
It leads me to another problem... how avoid that many (+100) processes from being created (and not killed).

Comment: Your apache i think is wrong configurated. Google about httpd `MaxClients` directive.

Comment: Possible, apache processes not closed because of not correct ended php scripts.